# Как анимировать элементы с последнего до первого?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть анимация на странице, при клике появляются элементы, один за другим с 1 по 5.
Как сделать так, чтобы при повторном нажатии, элементы исчезали в обратном направлении один за другим (`5,4 - 1`)?

```
$(".menu-bars").click(function() {
        $(".menu-bars").toggleClass("change");
        $(".main-nav").toggleClass("active");
        if ($(".main-nav").hasClass("active")) {
            var i = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
                if (list.length > i) {
                    list[i++].style.opacity = "1"; 
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 60);
        } else {
            var i = 0;
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
                if (list.length > i) {
                    list[i++].style.opacity = "0"; 
                } else {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                }
            }, 60);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
for (var i = list.length-1; i > -1; i--){
    setInterval(function() {
        list[i].style.opacity = "0"; 
    }, 60 + (i * 10));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так?

```js
let container   = document.querySelector('#wrapper'),
    showBtn     = document.querySelector('#show'),
    hideBtn     = document.querySelector('#hide'),
    isInserting = false;
    
function insertEl(text){
  let el = document.createElement('DIV'),
      color = Array(...Array(6)).reduce(_ => _ += '0123456789ABCDEF'[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)], '#');

  el.style.background = color;
  el.style.color = 'white';
  el.innerText = text;
  container.appendChild(el);
}
    
showBtn.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  let i = 1;
  
  isInserting = true;
  
  let interval = setInterval(_ => {
    insertEl(i);
  
    if(++i > 5){
      isInserting = false;
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 200);
});

// Сокрытие
hideBtn.addEventListener('click', _ => {
  // Если идёт вставка, выходим
  if(isInserting)
    return;
    
  // Устанавливаем индекс максимального потомка - 1
  let i = container.children.length - 1;
  
  // Тут i: 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
  let interval = setInterval(_ => {
    // Удаляем соответствующий узел
    container.children[i].remove();
  
    // Если дошли до минимального
    if(--i < 0)
      // Выключаем интервал
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, 200);
});
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'></div>
<input type='button' id='show' value='Show' /> | <input type='button' id='hide' value='Hide' />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");
var i = list.length-1;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if ( i > -1) {
    list[i--].style.opacity = "0"; 
  }
}, 60);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149911)